# Passing pair return value to another function directly

Tags: go

I call a function that returns a pair (in the example os.Open) and I want to pass the returned pair directly as argument to another function (without using intermediate variables). I have tried the two following ways, unsuccessfully.
Other languages (like F#) allow to perform pattern matching on function call. How can I achieve the same in Go?

```
func checkError(f *os.File, e error, m string) interface{} {
    if e != nil {
        /*Print m and panic*/
    }
    return f
}

func f1(path string) {
    checkError(os.Open(path), "Can't Open File") //ERROR
}
```

```
func checkError((f *os.File, e error), m string) interface{} { //ERROR
    if e != nil { /*Print m and panic*/}
    return f
}

func f1(path string) {
    checkError(os.Open(path), "Can't Open File")
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You cannot, go does not have such a syntax.

Comment: It's not really clear what `checkError` is meant to do. It's defined using invalid syntax, so the intention is not clear. Is it meant to take a function as the first argument? Or is it meant to take the output of a function as its first two arguments?

Comment: What you're trying to do is more typical of a functional language. Go docs recommend to "not try to be too clever"

Comment: You cannot and this is good. Consider: `func one() int; func two() (int, int); fun f (a, b, c int);` Now you could call f both ways: `f(one(), two())` and `f(two(), one())` without any hint from the compiler. Go tries to disallow anything that potentially could lead to errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing this would result in ambiguous behaviour; but you could close over the last argument and return a partially applied function:

```golang
func checkError(m string) func(*os.File, error) {
    return func(f *os.File, e error) {
    if e != nil {
        // do stuff with m
    }
}

checkError("Can't Open File")(os.Open(path))
```

Or, the other way around:

```golang
func checkError(f *os.File, e error) func(string) {
    return func(m string) {
    if e != nil {
        // do stuff with m
    }
}

checkError(os.Open(path))("Can't Open File")
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it a little inconsistent because the following works fine, but when the extra positional argument is added the compiler doesn't like it.

```
func checkError(f *os.File, e error) interface{} {
    if e != nil {
        /*Print m and panic*/
    }
    return f 
}

func f1(path string) {
    checkError(os.Open(path)) //ERROR
}
```

Obviously you could just push the return value directly, not sure you lose much since you'll panic if error isn't nil

```
func checkError(f *os.File, e error, m string) interface{} {
    if e != nil {
        /*Print m and panic*/
    }
    return f
}

func f1(path string) {
    file, e := os.Open(path)
    checkError(file, e, "Can't Open File")
}
```

Another thought is you could pass the function and do the work in `checkError`

```
 type OsFunction func(string)(* os.File, error)

 func checkError(osFunction OsFunction, path string, m string) interface{} {
   f, e := osFunction(path)
   if e != nil {
     /*Print m and panic*/
   }
   return f
 }

 func f2(path string) {
   checkError2(os.Open, path, "Can't Open File")
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Jack hint I remembered that functions can also be returned.
The following solution works for me

```
func checkError(r interface{}, e error) func(string) interface{} {
    return func(m string) interface{} {
        if e != nil {
            /*Print m and panic*/
        }
        return r
    }
}

func f1(path string) {
    checkError(os.Open(path))("Can't open file")
}
```